# Retrofit creating endpoints using @Path and @Query parameter

Tags: android, api, retrofit

I had to call api endpoints on this query url `/api/AssignedStaffClassSection/?StaffId=3071` I tried this way but failed.

Option 1 using `@Query` parameter

```
 @GET(WebSchoolApi._SAPI + "/AssignedStaffClassSection/")
Call<StaffAssignedClassSectionModel> getAssignedClassSection(@Query("StaffId") String staffId);
```

Option 2 using `@Path` parameter

```
 @GET(WebSchoolApi._SAPI + "/AssignedStaffClassSection/?StaffId={staffId}")
    Call<StaffAssignedClassSectionModel> getAssignedClassSection(@Path("staffId") String _staffid);
```

Is there any mistake that I made over?

Thank your for your help.

Comment: How does it fail? When Does it fail? your WebSchoolApi.SAPI has to terminate with "/" and you also have "/" at the start of you path, which means you have a URL with "//" in it

Comment: The first option is correct. Are you logging the response to see what's being sent to your api?

Comment: @Hector relative url for WebSchoolApi.SAPI is not terminated with '/' as you can see public static final String _SAPI = "/api". Anyway thank you for your concern. I am going to trace the log report first.

Comment: I solved this problem as it was problem with mapping response as a list of StaffAssignedClassSectionModel instead. Bwy Thank you for your help and suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For GET request you mast to use:

```
example.com/api/AssignedStaffClassSection/?StaffId=3071
```

Correct:

```
@GET(WebSchoolApi._SAPI + "/AssignedStaffClassSection/")
Call<StaffAssignedClassSectionModel> getAssignedClassSection(@Query("StaffId") String staffId);
```

You should to use @Path for

```
example.com/api/AssignedStaffClassSection/3071/StaffId
```

And it will looks like:

```
@GET(WebSchoolApi._SAPI + "/AssignedStaffClassSection/{staffId}/StaffId")
Call<StaffAssignedClassSectionModel> getAssignedClassSection(@Path("staffId") String _staffid);
```

Crash may produce if you use wrong tool.